# Apache Ranger check installed version

Tags: apache, hadoop

As in the title, how can I check the current installed version of apache ranger? Both shell or ui check are accepted

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you still need this answer. Under ranger installation directory, there would be a file called "version" which contains the version of Ranger being used. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Vijay, how to check Ranger version via UI or REST API?